# Finding Bezier Curve Line

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to adjust/change the bezier curve and the blue line is not in the f- curve editor window like the instructions say it should be. Is there something I am missing or is there a way to get it back? I copied the instructions below and attached an image of what it looks like from my point of view. Any help would be great!!

In these steps, you'll move the whole Bezier curve to change the door-opening animation.

In the 3D View window, make sure that the house's door is still selected. If not, right-click to select it.
With the mouse pointer located in the F Curve Editor window, rotate the mouse scroll wheel upward to zoom in on the Bezier curve.
TIP: If you can't see it, rotate the scroll wheel downward to zoom out.
Right-click and drag the Bezier curve to unstick it. The Bezier curve will follow the mouse pointer wherever you move it in the F Curve Editor window.
TIP: Right-clicking again will return the curve to its starting point.
When you've moved it to a new spot, left-click to stop moving the curve.
TIP: You can always press CTRL + Z to undo the movement and return the curve to its previous spot. If you want to undo something in the F Curve Editor, make sure the mouse pointer is in that window.
Press ALT + A to see the new door-opening animation.[image]

Comment: At what point and how did you add the keyframes?

Comment: I think you missed a step, see the triangle beside the Rotation, under Plane.001.action in the F-curve editor, if you click that triangle it will expand downwards and show the beziers for x, y, z

Comment: It may just be out of view, with the mouse over the graph editor press `Home` to bring all curves into view. If you don't have a home key the menu is `View->View All`

Comment: Thank you all so much! I will try these options and see if they work!